# Reflecting HTML List Sorting Order in Knockout ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I have a small Knockout JS which populates a list from a knockout observableArray. Now I have made the list sortable by html property, no special functionality from js or any custom knockout template. Now the list can be sorted as drag drop, just what I needed but it does not reflect in knockout. Probably because its just a change in UI representation from html but the elements of ObservableArray themselves are not changing. Now how do I achieve this with minimal change.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3somre/1/

html:

```
<ul id="sortable" sortable="true" style="list-style:none" data-bind="foreach: columns">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<textarea data-bind="text:columns"></textarea>
```

script:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.columns = ko.observableArray(["Jenny","Jennifer","Bob","Cat","Billy"]);
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
};
```

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

Comment: Welcome. Can you explain what you mean by "does not reflect in knockout"?

Comment: If you see the js fiddle I posted, sort the list in UI does not change the actual order of elements in the list. I display the list in a text area as well. Changing the order of the list does not change the order of things in the text area, meaning knockout observable hierarchy is not getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery in your viewmodel code is telling you you need a custom binding handler. https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a custom binding for that. And one is already available [here](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable).

It will be something like

```
<ul data-bind="sortable: columns">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79caepvx/

Comment: Thanks Dandy, I already saw this, but its a custom binding written by someone else and I can't use it without including the license and that goes into someone reviewing it in office and approvals and what not nonsense. Is there no way to capture the state of UI. Now I think, can't I get the HTML element, the list, and read back and use it in that order, because I need to use that order only when user presses an OK button, I don't essentially need it to be dynamic.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Instead of using the knockout observableArray, I got the html element and iterated over its child list and got the sorted order :)